# `eb config save`: The specified key does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Why is it saving configuration is giving me S3 error?

[image]

The configuration is actually saved. I can see it in aws console:

[image]

and in the S3 bucket:

[image]

But not locally in `.elasticbeanstalk/`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Double which application eb cli is using. The eb cli allows you to operate on Environment which are not part of the Application which is currently selected by the EB CLI. To fix it you can `eb init` again or change directory to a dir which has been initialized with the right application.

I realize I'm answer far too late to help with the original question, but I arrived here by google search, so I'm hoping to help someone further down the timestream.

Comment: As a follow-up to this answer, I can confirm that running `eb init` again does, indeed, work, but you need to provide the environment name (and possibly the region) when running `eb init`. Then the config will save locally. (Did for me anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure check the application name is correct on the eb config file in the app, if you have one.

This guide maybe helpful: https://medium.com/@iranr/elastic-beanstalk-how-to-rename-your-aws-elastic-beanstalk-application-15cd4dbaca11